# Exported STL is empty in Slic3r

Tags: export, 3d-printing, stl

I am having trouble exporting meshes as .stl files from blender, when I import the exported mesh into Slic3r nothing shows up. However when I import an already existing model into blender and then export that as a .stl, it works fine in Slic3r

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27253)**

**[stl file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/wz8exb)**

Comment: upload your blend file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: upload your stl file here: https://www.sendspace.com/

Comment: in case anyone else is having this same problem 7 years later, I was able to fix it by closing everything, restarting my computer, and trying again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to triangulate the mesh. Select the mesh you wish to export and add a Triangulate Modifier to it. Then in the .stl export dialogue enable Apply Modifiers.

[image]

[image]

`.stl` imported to slic3r

[image: enter code here]

---

### GIF

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer, however, it does not work for me. I can reimport the STL and I will see my model. However, in Slic3r I can only see the plane.

Comment: @Rogier I added a gif, hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks! When I do it like you do, it does work (also for the cube). I found that as soon as I give it dimensions, in cm's (i.e. 20x20x20cm), somehow there is only one plane left. The dimensions for x and y are gone: so the size in Slic3r is 0.00x0.00x0.20.. Any clue why?

Comment: I am glad it worked. Slic3r is not an app I actually use, so I don't know why it is behaving like that.

Comment: Which gcode generating app do you use? Because I would really like to get my model into gcode :)

Comment: I don't use any. I do not 3d print

Comment: Since this does mostly answer my question, I'll accept this as the answer. The missing part (scene scale etc) can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing

Answer (score 3):

For me to get this to work. I changed units to metric. To create a 2cm cube I had to create a cube and set the scale to 2cm. I made sure that I applied the scale to the cube so that it says:

scale x: 1
scale y: 1
scale z: 1

length: 2cm
width:  2cm
height: 2cm

Then I exported selected as *.STL and dragged into Slic3r. From there I applied a scale of "100,000" as "100" was default. YES you heard that right 100k. I'm not sure why this happening but it works for me and I measured my model after i printed it and it's 2cm square. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to select your model before exporting to STL.

The export turns up empty when no object is selected.

Check the file size for the STL file after export. It should be bigger than 100 bytes or so. My empty file is 84 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did select the object, for some models it does export and for some it doesn't. My STL is probably empty, since it is very small. I added the files to my post.

Comment: After reimporting the STL in blender, I can see the model. However, in Slic3r I can only see the plane. Atleast no model...

Comment: I notice the same thing. The meshes which Blender can not export as STL are all 84 bytes. Any ideas of how to debug this situation? I've already checked my normals

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying this. My model is in blender units, and I had the same problem.

If your blender model is in blender units, you have to scale x 1.000, as one blender unit is a millimeter in slic3r. Try this and tell us if you solved the problem.

Comment: I wonder if this means the model is actually there but it's a 1000x too big so it doesn't show??

Answer (score -1):

I had to combine answers from this post to get Blender's STL exports to work.

1. Select all (shortcut `a`) before exporting per Gunslinger or you get the 84-byte empty STL file.
2. The units do not export correctly per Kyle Mayne. I'm not using Slic3r so I used 3D Builder to adjust the units as shown in [this YouTube walkthrough](https://youtu.be/ROwdFy7HbA0?t=399) before opening the STL in my slicing program.