# Blender + Slic3r: scaling bug?

Tags: 3d-printing

I create some models for 3D-printing, and as are several cm large I use scaling 0.01 (1 cm). Then I convert the result to .stl and pass it to Slic3r to create .gcode. What I expect is scaling back by *100 will give me the correct result. However, in that case I get models 10 times smaller, and scaling by *1000 does the job. I wonder if I don't understand smth or it's a bug of either Blender or Slic3r. So, it this a bug? How to check if it's because of Blender of Slic3r?

Comment: This question should give you answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing