# 3D print tablet wall recessed mount incomplete

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a simple 3D print of a recessed wall trim for a tablet. It isn't showing as a solid piece when I try to print. Can someone help me out?
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
without the curved ends

Comment: If you have made improvements as indicated below then update your file.

Comment: Try scaling whole model down and applying scale (`Ctrl`+`A`). The model has 256 meters long and it's may be too much. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data for applying scale and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing for units for 3d printing.

Answer (score 1):

Newer

**Normals Recalculate Outside**

[image]

Edit Older Disregard

Use Make Normals Consistent.  This will help.

[image]

Comment: Already did that. No good