# using Blender with anycubic photon printer

Tags: export

I have designed two parts I wish to print in HO scale.

A drawing of a brick wall in 1:1 scale and exported to .stl comes into Anycubic Photon screen so small it is almost invisable.

Have not been able to change the size no matter what I do. Any help out there?

Comment: There is a scale property as part of the export dialog (on the right side of the file browser), hotkey is `N`...

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Scale settings for exporting to STL (for 3d printing)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing)